# Escalation workflow rule for case

Tags: case, escalation

So...I created a checkbox formula field on a case that clicks true if the following criteria are met:

```
IF( (TODAY()> Contact_Cust_Identify_Issues__c ) && 
    ISBLANK(Contacted_Customer_Date__c) 
    ,true,false
)
```

I then created a workflow that SHOULD trigger an email and create a completed task that states the email was sent. I chose to have the workflow evaulate each time the case meets criteria. The workflow is not firing.

Here is the workflow rule:

```
(Case: Case Record TypeEQUALSCase; VOC Response Plan) AND
(Case: > 2 DaysEQUALSTrue) AND (Case: StatusEQUALSNew)
```

Is the formula field update not considered an edit? What am I doing wrong here?

If I create a workflow rule that updates the field instead of a formula field, will this trigger an escalation?

Comment: Please explain what it supposed to do and when to be triggered, not just what you tried. It looks for me like you need a time-dependant action on a workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, formulas are actually calculated "on the fly", and thus don't count as an "edit" on a record. In general, you should avoid coding dates into workflow filters, because they also won't fire correctly (because the rule won't match when the record is originally edited, so they won't be queued to execute).

So, your filter would probably be:

```
Case: Status equals New
    AND
Case: Case Record Type equals Case; VOC Response Plan
```

Then, you just need to make sure you've already calculated the correct date somehow, and use that date as the Time Based Workflow fire time. For workflow rules with Time Based Workflow actions, if the record is subsequently modified before the rule fires (say, the status changes to In Progress), the queued action will be removed from the Time Based Workflow Queue, and no action will be taken.

Comment: So I do have another formula field that takes the created date and adds 2 business days to get the "Contact Customer Due Date". I can't wrap my head around the part where it wants me to put a time on the workflow. The reason is due to business days. Would I say 1 day after Contact Customer Due Date? It would be late at that point right? I think I may have answered my own question here...with your help of course!